# What a warm welcome this user got :(

Tags: discussion, new-users, be-nice

Please remember to give new users a little time and encourgment when they don't put enough information in the post. I know we need more information to help but honestly if I was this person I'm not sure I would bother now or ever come back to the site. Please remember the only way we can grow is to help new users learn the site.

3 downvotes and closed in less than 4 hours.

[2004 chevy trailblazer check engine light on no codes provided when checking with reader only blank sc](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/37547/85)

Comment: I like the new tag :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score 5):

Rebuke taken.  I was one of the ones who voted to close, while not one who voted down.  And you're right.  To produce a more welcome environment, what I should have done is to have dropped a comment asking for more information.

I remember vividly my first post on here; what drew me to this site and made me stay was simply the atmosphere of welcome.  In an unfortunate switch of events, I confess that I have failed to demonstrate that same environment.

Here's my hope: **Better today than yesterday; better tomorrow than today.**  I think we can all continue to improve.  I hope we can all learn a valuable lesson from this incident: Think twice before closing.  Could we keep an eye on it a bit longer and help this new user improve their post?

Comment: You were only one of a few that did. I just want people to give a new user a little more leeway on their first question.